# SQL Server Management Studio: How to export/ import credentials

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

From one PC to another, I intend to export and import the credentials saved in my SSMS.
My SSMS has some SQL Server authentication-based credentials saved for a couple of cloud DBs. Going through all of them and saving their credentials on my new PC will take significant effort and time.
I observed that SSMS credentials are stored in the Windows credential manager. I tried exporting them from the first PC to the second one.
The credentials have been successfully imported to the second PC.
However, still, when I open the SSMS, the credentials are not shown/ loaded.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances) help you?

Comment: [The answers here may be useful](https://serverfault.com/q/318692) but the "couple of cloud DBs" might be different. @diiN__________ I think that is slightly different, it's the official guidance for migrating logins between instances of SQL Server, not migrating credentials _used to access SQL Server_ between client workstations.